# What's the use-case for the Azure App assigned address feature?

Tags: azure

I am trying to understand the `Function app -> Networking -> App assigned address` functionality.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#app-assigned-address) say:

> The app-assigned address feature is an offshoot of the IP-based SSL capability. You access it by setting up SSL with your app. You can use this feature for IP-based SSL calls. You can also use it to give your app an address that only it has.

I still don't get it. "You can also use it to give your app an address that only it has." well isn't that trivial, that an address is unique to an app? When would I use the `App assigned address` feature and for which use case?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the IP address of your function app instance might change due to scaling, maintenance, redeployment, or other reasons. By using the App assigned address feature, you ensure that your function app always has a consistent IP address, which can be beneficial for stability and compatibility with external systems

If you're integrating your function app with a third-party service that requires you to provide an IP address for communication, the App assigned address feature allows you to provide a fixed IP address for this purpose

So that you can redeploy your function in different subscriptions/resource groups/regions/etc., but the app-assigned address remains the same, and you will not be required to update third-party service configurations